# How to perform an efficient Order By in this particular scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

So I am writing this query, it works fine:

```
(from schools in context.Schools
                           // some kind of fancy joins
                           select new SomeLocalDTO()
                           {
                               SchoolId = schools.SchoolId,
                               FancySchoolName = schools.SchoolId + "**** -*****  " + schools.SchoolName

                            })
                        .AsQueryable();
/// I have some fancy code here which will aslso take care of take/skip.
// I WANT TO DO ORDER BY HERE, after the skip and take
```

The problem is I want to order by after doing all the fancy code/ take skip. But the problem is I do not have school name in the select statement, instead what I have is FancySchoolName. What should I do?

Note 1: I can not change SomeLocalDTO, to inlclude schoolname in the select.
Note 2: As per my business requirment, I do not care if I get ABC or FED in my result from ABCDEF. 
Note 3: I know its an odd request, just its a weird business requirement.

Comment: Your `AsQueryable` call isn't accomplishing anything.  The object is already an `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: @Obviously, you still want the Orderby to be on `SchoolName` though, correct?

Comment: What makes you think your current code doesn't emit the correct SQL? Since Linq uses deferred execution (and your sets are `IQueryable` all the way), there's a good chance your `orderby` will be taken into account even if you're using `Skip()` and `Take()` later.

Comment: Good chance? Or a sure thing?

Comment: @Obviously Of course, if you want to know for sure you only need to run the code once to find out for yourself.

Comment: @Obviously, "Good chance" because I didn't see that "fancy code" you're chaining to it. But, by leveraging deferred execution, Linq (by design) will take all the requirements you put into the query (projection, filtering, paging and sorting) and try to execute the best SQL query that will satisfy those requirements.

Comment: @Obviously Once you have weird request, why don't you remove the `orderby` from your example, add the "fancy" code with take/skip/whatever and mark the place where you need the `orderby` to happen. A lot of people here are trying to help you, why don't you help them better understand your needs, rather than putting puzzles.

Comment: Done, removed that order by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just create a subclass of `SomeLocalDTO` that DOES include `SchoolName`, have your LINQ create those objects, and then just downcast to `SomeLocalDTO` when you return to the caller.

**UPDATE:**

Based on everything you've said, this is how I am still interpreting what you want...an OrderBy/Take/Skip AFTER the initial query, yet still ordering by `SchoolName`:

```
public class MyDTO: SomeLocalDTO
{
   public string SchoolName {get;set;}
}

var result = (from schools in context.Schools
                           // some kind of fancy joins
                           select new MyDTO()
                           {
                               SchoolId = schools.SchoolId,
                               FancySchoolName = schools.SchoolId + "**** -*****  " + schools.SchoolName,
                               SchoolName = schools.SchoolName    
                            });

return result.OrderBy(s => s.SchoolName)
             .Skip(...)
             .Take(...)
             .Cast<SomeLocalDTO>();
```

Comment: Just use the base class.  Don't need another.

Comment: OP says he cannot change the base class.

Comment: The `schools` base class has everything he needs.

Comment: @RobertMcKee But the query is projecting to `SomeLocalDTO` which OP states cannot be changed.

Comment: Yeah I guess, I can do that. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertMcKee, if he needs the OrderBy AFTER the LINQ statement, he'll need this.  There's details we don't know due to the "fancy joins" being clipped that could hinder doing the take/skip/orderby within the LINQ statement itself.

Comment: @SteveDanner I would have either used the `schools` object which has everything (SchoolId,SchoolName) he needs to do the projection at the end, or used an anonymous object, but both might require slight changes to "fancy code" that is between the query and the take/skip while yours does not.  Especially if they are in separate modules.

Answer (score 2):

That is a really odd request to order by, do take/skip, and then a different order by, but:

```
var something=(from schools in context.Schools
  // some kind of fancy joins
  orderby schools.Name
  select schools);
// take/skip
var result=something.OrderBy(...).Select(schools=>
  new SomeLocalDTO()
  {
    SchoolId = schools.SchoolId,
    FancySchoolName = schools.SchoolId + "**** -*****  " + schools.SchoolName
  });
```

Based on your confusion, I suspect this is what you want:

```
var something=context.Schools
  .OrderBy(schools=>schools.SchoolName)
  .Skip(...)
  .Take(...)
  .Select(schools=>
    new SomeLocalDTO()
    {
      SchoolId = schools.SchoolId,
      FancySchoolName = schools.SchoolId + "**** -*****  " + schools.SchoolName
    });
```

Comment: I just want to do one order by and that is after the skip and take code. I will remove the order by before select.

Comment: @Obviously This maintains that behavior from the code in your question.

Comment: @Obviously You can't/shouldn't do a take/skip on unordered results, and if you only wanted to do one orderby, then just put it in the orderby you already have.

Comment: Its just a business requirment

Comment: @Obviously Without the orderby, the results are in an unpredictable order.   The results could come as "A,B,C" or "B,C,A" or "C,A,B" orders (or any other combination), and it isn't guaranteed to come in that same order the next time you ask.  Taking and Skipping makes little sense in that case, which is why you can't do it.

Comment: I know, its a weird business requirment. I do not care, if i get, A,B,C or C,B,A

Comment: @Obviously But, if you are doing skip/take, then you are usually doing pagination.  So the first time your code executes you get "ABCDEFGH", you are on the first page so you `.Skip(0)` and `.Take(5)` which gives you "ABCDE", then you hit the next page button, your code runs again, but this time the query returns "FGHADEFC", and you `.Skip(5)` and `.Take(5)` which gives you "EFC" which isn't what anyone would ever expect since they have already seen E and C on the previous page, and you didn't show them G or H yet.  They click the first page button and this time you get...YUCK